# Body and Background sections separate using CSS

Tags: html, css, background

How do I separate the body/content area of my site from the background using CSS. To show you what I mean, just see the attached picture. So, the background on the sides will expand to people with really big monitors, but the content are will always stay the same size.

Thanks,
Amar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lavnv.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 50px;
}

#content {
  width: 960px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: How do I put a black border around the outside of the content area?

Comment: border: 1px solid #000; or outline: 1px solid #000; 
Note that outline doesn't work well in IE7.

Comment: Thanks, I'd vote you up but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: No worries :) Welcome to Stackoverflow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

use the following CSS :

```
content {
  width: 980px; // or your desired width
  margin: 0 auto; // horizontally center it
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/SsPGS/

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
  width:600px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}   

<div id="content">
    Your content goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background-color: #f0e0af;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  background-color: #fbf6e2;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`.container`  is a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, what you seek is a wrapper.

Put the background image on the body, and then, use a div with this css rule for the content:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can use it in html like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 Content here
</div>
```

The WIDTH value must be the exactly size you want for your "content box" and the margin property just centralize it no matter the size of the monitor.